# Character issue in WordPress site

Tags: database, wordpress, character, woocommerce

I have a problem with a WordPress site (it's in Swedish). For some reason I can't use all characters when I'm writing posts - the characters å, ä and ö become Ã¥ Ã¤ Ã¶. The site is a webshop and I have the Woocommerce plugin installed. The same problem with åäö occurs in the long product descriptions of Woocommerce.

Anyone know what I can do to solve this? The character encoding in WordPress admin panel is set to UTF-8 and so is the database charset in wp-config.

In the database in phpmyadmin the collation of the wp-posts tables are set to "utf8_general_ci". Is that the problem?

This thing has never happened to me before, even though I have built a lot of WP sites in the past. Therefore I don't know what to do. Maybe the solution is simple but I want to know what I'm doing before doing anything so I don't risk messing up the site.

Would really appreciate some help with this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When "national special characters", ie. non-ASCII characters, are displayed wrong, you probably have an error related to charset. The easiest way to fix this is usually to make sure that you are using UTF-8 everywhere.

(For Swedish in particular, you can use ISO-8859-1 (worst), ISO-8859-15 (better) or UTF-8 (best).)

You need to use the same charset everywhere, from the database to the HTML declaration.

1. In your theme's header.php file, please make sure that the declared charset is
   UTF-8.
2. In your text editor or on your server, please make sure your theme files are being saved as UTF-8.
3. In MySQL, please make sure that the table schema is set to use utf-8.
4. In MySQL, please make sure that connections default to use UTf-8: `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`
5. In PHP, try setting the connection to utf-8 with [mysqli_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php)

Comment: Point 2 finally saved my life after HOURS! Why can't we all speak english, this would be so much easier :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix the Character Encoding Mismatch Problem in WordPress, 
Open the ‘wp-config.php’ file in a text editor(the wp-config.php file can be found on the directory where you installed WordPress).
Find the following two lines and comment them out:

```
define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

They should look like the following after you comment them out:

```
//define(‘DB_CHARSET’, ‘utf8′);
//define(‘DB_COLLATE’, ”);
```

Now upload the updated ‘wp-config.php’ file to your webhost.

This character encoding problem can happen after a database upgrade too so it doesn’t hurt to keep this trick in your mind just in case.

Comment: It is not recommended to comment out the `DB_CHARSET` variable. COLLATE can be commented out.

Answer (score 0):

In another case, **if you are using PHP Dom (loadHTML)** somewhere, there is a need to load HTML as UTF-8. I have **fixed** it by:

Replacing

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
```

to

```
@$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html);
```